# C++ preprocessor ensure globally unique string

Tags: c++, gcc, macros, c-preprocessor

I have a Macro function which takes a name and is intended to be called from various namespaces. I want to ensure that this name be unique globally. The define looks something like this:

```
#define DECLARE_NEW_MYVAR( Name ) static MyVar Name( #Name )
```

I want this static variable to be namespaced (which is why I expect it to be called from various namespaces) but I also need to ensure that the string being passed to the constructor of MyVar is globally unique. This is because I am going to serialize this value and I need to be able to associate it back correctly.

A few things that I tried without success:

**To Force it to be Unique:** Based on some information append something to the name to force it to be unique

- Use the `__COUNTER__` macro: One of the compilers I am targeting does not have this Macro. Also, it seems dangerous to assume that the order in which the Macro is called will be the same
- Use the `__FILE__` macro: This has the entire filepath which is good to make sure that it is unique, but if compiled from a different place or a different machine, the deserialization would no longer work.

**To Check if it is Unique:** Leave it up to the caller for it to be globally unique and  have the compiler complain if it is not

- I was looking for a way to declare something in the global namespace from within a namespace so that I could at least cause a multiply defined symbols if they don't make it unique. I couldn't figure out a way to do this.

Basically I need to come up with a globally unique string to pass to MyVar that I can trust will not change between different compilations and preferably not change between code changes (as long as the specific call hasn't been changed).

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: `__FILE__` won't work in any case, as it expands to a string constant and there's no way to extract its contents.  I rather think you're up a creek here.

Comment: A string constant is what I want (`__FILE__` would be concatenated with Name for the paramater to MyVar). I don't need the variable name itself to be unique since it will be in its own namespace. The compiler will ensure that it is unique within its namespace.

Comment: Why not have your ```DECLARE_NEW_MYVAR``` take a string as a second argument that's something globally unique like a GUID. That'd help with the make it stable but unique.

Comment: I was hoping to either not require the consumer of this define to ensure it is unique, or at least be able to have the compiler verify that it is unique. If I took a second parameter that is the key I would still want a way to ensure that it is in fact unique.

Comment: Well, do you really need a string? The address of the created object, for example, is guaranteed to be unique, and you get it "for free". You could sprintf it into a string :-)

Comment: But the address of the object can (and probably will) change when recompiling (on a different host).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove the prefix to the project directory from `__FILE__` like this:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

#define COMMON_PATH_PREFIX "/home/user/path/to/project/"

#define UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER() (__FILE__ + std::strlen(COMMON_PATH_PREFIX))

void someFunction(const char *identifier)
{
    std::cout << identifier << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    someFunction(UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER());
}
```

The `COMMON_PATH_PREFIX` could be `#define`'d by your build system. If you use CMake for example you could simply use `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIRECTORY`.

The call to `std::strlen()` should be optimized out by your compiler, since the string is constant and known at compile time.

Of course this only works if you only want to declare one variable per file. You could also add `__LINE__` to the identifier, but then it's much more likely that the identifier changes if you change your code.

Comment: I think this is going to be the best solution. Still has some weirdness considering there will be multiple declarations in a single file. Instead I decided to just validate the uniqueness of the string at runtime.